# How can I refresh multiple sheets (in specific order) in an Excel workbook using EPM references?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-epm

I have a workbook with about 50 sheets to be refreshed in a certain order (to avoid #rfr errors, since the sheets build off of one another).

The refresh is done via the EPM add in for Excel.  I have activated the FPMXLclient functions and have attempted to write some code.  I am very inexperienced with coding and logic.  In the workbook the macro needs to start at the last tab, wait for the sheet to refresh, then move on to the next tab (and so on...).  Below is an example of some of the VBA code I have written:

```
    Dim refreshList
        refreshList = Array("BS Analytic", "Balance Sheet")
        'There are more than just the 2 in the array (~50)
    Sub test_loop()
        Dim I
        For I = LBound(refreshList) To UBound(refreshList)
        MsgBox refreshList(I)
        Next I
    End Sub
    'Vba to refresh data
    Dim client As New EPMAddInAutomation
    Sub Refresh_Click()
        client.Refresh
    End Sub
    Sub AFTER_REFRESH()
        MsgBox "done"
    End Sub
```

Other info: This involves BPC and SAP too.

Comment: You should find a more specific question to ask here. Put this way, your question is of no use to the community.

Comment: Do you have a link to a EMP VBA developers guide? unless you can pass a parameter into the `Refresh` method telling it a specific sheet to refresh, then you can't do this in order. However IMHO running a system from a 50 sheet excel model is a technical liability.

Comment: Alex, I understand where you are coming from on this.  At the time of posting I considered it specific enough due to the fact that I could not find an answer elsewhere, but I will keep what you said in mind for future postings.
Electric, I do not believe I have access to the developers guide.  Thank you for your input and I am certainly aware of the technical liability involved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your addin refreshes the active sheet, something like this in your loop might work:

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Set Sh = WorkSheets(RefreshList(I))
Sh.Activate
Client.Refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have each sheet number in the array `refreshList` and then use `For each I in refreshList`. That will then propagate the `refreshList` in the order for each update. If it is also moving from the last sheet backwards you could always do the following:

```
Sub Refresh_Click

Dim refreshList() As Integer
reDim refreshList(50)
for i = 0 to 49
    refreshList(i) = 50 - i
next
For each I in refreshList
    Sheets(I).EnableCalculation = false
    Sheets(I).EnableCalculation = true
Next
MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, Moiety.  I had to go into VBA and re-number the sheets in the correct order as they were not before.  When I attempted to run your code I got an error message "Compile Error: Invalid outside procedure".  Do you have any insight on what could be done to fix this?  Maybe it is user-error on my part...

Comment: I have ammended the code to be inclusive in just one `sub`. I assume `Refresh_Click` is a macro run when a button or some type is clicked. The code above should refresh each page in order.